# Telerik RadControl(ASP.NET AJAX): Can't find control using suggested method

Tags: asp.net, jquery, telerik

We are using Telerik radcontrols in our web form and I am trying to solve an annoying problem for a while. According to Telerik, I should be able to find my control from client-side using the following method,

```
var element = $find('<%= dateSampleDate.RadDatePicker_ClientId %>');
```

[A little clarification about the statement above: This RadDatePicker is wrapped inside a custom control so I had to expose the ClientId explicitely using a public property; hence the weird looking client id call. Also, the above statement is being called from a javascript function which is attached to a Peter Blum custom validator's CustomEvalFunctionName property and all of my scripts are written at page bottom so that scripts doesn't hamper the loading of DOM.]

Problem is, element is ALWAYS null [checked using FireBug js debugger]. Is that a timing issue?

Suggestions from anyone with experience would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Would be great to get an answer on this:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a timing issue. I think the code is executed before the Ajax components are initialized. You can check [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20081218061017/http://blogs.telerik.com/DimoDimov/Posts/08-12-13/Don_t_Use_BODY_ONLOAD_in_ASP_NET_AJAX_Websites.aspx) blog post which could be useful.

Comment: Thanks, the Sys.Application.add_load(funcName) finally made it work for me.

Comment: I updated the answer with a new link because the previous version was no longer working.  It would be helpful if you could include some of the content from the link here in this answer in the event it ever fails again.